# Concurrency issue while deleteing related tables

Tags: entity-framework, concurrency

I am using Dbcontext to provide and ORM for my application, and I defined my entity classes as follow :

```
    public partial class Article
    {
     public int ArticleID { get; set; }

     //other properties

        [ConcurrencyCheck]
        [Timestamp]
        public byte[] TimeStamp { get; set; } 

     public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; } 
}

 public partial class Comment
    {

        public int CommentID { get; set; }

        //other properties 

        public virtual Article Article { get; set; }

}
```

And for CRUD Operations I follow what you can read in this [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

But when I want to delete an article and its associated comments as follow :

```
var qry=from c in _articleRepo.GetArticleByID(id).Comments
                        select c;

                foreach (var item in qry)
                {
                    _commentRepo.DeleteComment(item.CommentID);

                    _commentRepo.Save();
                }



                _articleRepo.DeleteArticle(id);

                _articleRepo.Save();
```

removing comments works good, but when it comes to remove the article, the application throws this exception :

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected
>   number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since
>   entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.

any one can help me ?

Comment: I think you have to refresh the article entity, because even though you deleted the comments, the entity in memory still has them associated to the article. Another way is define the delete action as Cascade between Article and Comments, this way, when you delete an article it will cascade to the comments...

Comment: would you please explain more or provide a sample ?

Comment: Well I can't really say without knowing more about your context. Here is a shot in the dark, have you tried exactly as you have but removing this line: **_commentRepo.Save();** only saving with **_articleRepo.Save();**. I think that MIGHT help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are Saving your context one to many times...

Try removing the **_commentRepo.Save();** and just Save on **_articleRepo.Save();**

Hope this helps...

Comment: @persian When you tried to save your article, the entity still had the comments and it tried to save them as well, except they were already deleted from the db by the previous context.SaveChanges()...